# runtime error 1004 not inserted object

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i am getting runtime error 1004 not inserted object when i am uploading document in Ms Excel using OleObject. The detail of my code is given below. I will be thankful for guidance in this regard.

```
Private Sub UploadL2G_Click()

Dim hussain  As OLEObject
Dim eric As Variant

'Selection of the file
eric = Application.GetOpenFilename

If eric = False Then
    Exit Sub
    CheckL2G.Value = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End If

'Pasting the object in the wished cell

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("L2G").Range("D13").Select
'Insertion of the object
    Set hussain = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=eric, Link:=False, displayasicon:=True)
End With

CheckL2G.Value = True

'Size of the icon
hussain.Width = 30
hussain.Height = 30
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to embed/what is in `eric`?

Comment: Anything following `Exit Sub` will not be executed.

Comment: @Tabraiz Modify the `With` in the middle of your code  to 1) `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("L2G")`  2) `Set hussain = .OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=eric, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True)` 3) `End With`

Comment: @ Alex K  eric has been declared as object which is storing filename of the document which has to be uploaded in worksheet L2G using oleobject

Comment: @ Shai Rado Thanks for the guidance. I have one more question from you. If i want to add my file in range("D13") in excel sheet how i can add it in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think user Vityata's solution is completely correct. It should be:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("L2G")
    'Insertion of the object
    Set hussain = .OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=eric, Link:=False, displayasicon:=True)
End With
```

It selects the worksheet of the current workbook (if there are more workbooks open, you might want to replace the `ThisWorkbook` with `Workbooks("myName")`). It uses only the `.` in the `Set` statement because the correct workbook and sheet was already selected with the `With` statement.

Comment: @ Paul Ogilvie Thanks for your help. I have developed userform so that users can put data into excel workbook and they have to upload documents in the excel workbook. In my windows 7, the document is uploaded using the code which i have written in the start but for other users who using latest windows and excel 2016 version, it gives runtime error 1004 not insert object. I am confused about it?

Answer (score 0):

Lets guess...
Is it happening on this line:

`With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("L2G").Range("D13").Select`

If this is the case, delete the line and write the following:

`ThisWorkbook.Activate`

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("L2G").Activate`

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("L2G").Range("D13").Select`

Comment: Is the `Select` in the `With` legal? (I.e., does it yield an object for `With`)? I believe the `Activate` is not necessary for the `With`, but it would be necessary for the `ActiveSheet. ...`